# Cassandra is changing the position of timestamp column

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

I'm new in Cassandra and when I was copying a CSV in Cassandra I found a problem with the position of my timestamp column.
I'm using cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id int,
  type int,
  eventdate timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

select * from events;

 id | eventdata | type
----+-----------+------
```

Why is Cassandra changing the position of the timestamp column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `SELECT *` the columns come back ordered with keys first, and then the remaining fields in alpha-numeric (might be ascii-betical or ascii-numeric...not exactly sure) order.  If you want your columns returned in a specific order, you'll need to specify them (in that order) in your `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT id, type, eventdate FROM events;
```

Comment: I didn't knew about the alpha-numeric order. Thanks.